# Rails query include? an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I store an array of Section ids as integers. `event.sections #=> ["1","115","130"]`
There is no Events has_many Sections relationship. Maybe this is a problem. I only need id's from Section and nothing else, so I have the array of integers stored as a serialized string in Postgres.

I can do something like this, which returns an array of events:

```
Event.upcoming.select { |m| m.sections.include? @section.id.to_s}
```

Is there a way to query this to get back an ActiveRecord::Relation?

edit-----

My earlier select query is not correct, because if `@section.id = "1"` then it will match and select events with these id's `"1", "10", "21", "100"`

This is the proper select statement:

`Event.upcoming.select {|e| ( e.newsletters.split(",").flatten.grep /^#{@section.id.to_s}$/ ).presence }`

Comment: Did you mean `{ |m| m.sections.include? @section.id.to_s}` and not `m.newsletters` ?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4953970/17410. Probably not much help, but good for a laugh :)

Comment: Ha! Going with it has bitten me a couple times already. I'm thinking of giving in, and refactoring to use a has_many relationship.